# Line is shown as not executed

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this code:

```
public function checkKeyConstraint($key) {
    if ($this->hasKey($key)) {
        throw new Exception('Key already exists '.$key);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Also i have two PHPUnit test methods with data providers, one for existent keys and the other for non-existent. **The problem** is that `throw new Exceptions('Key already exists '.$key);` **line is shown** by the code coverage tool **as a not executed**.

PHP_CodeCoverage 1.1.3, PHPUnit 3.6.12, PHP 5.4.4, xdebug 2.2.1-5.4-vc9

UPD: test methods and data providers

```
/**
 * @covers            Dict::checkKeyConstraint
 *
 * @dataProvider      providerNonexistentKeys
 */
public function testCheckKeyConstraintNonExistent($key) {
    $this->assertEquals(self::$object, self::$object->checkKeyConstraint($key));
}

/**
 * @covers            Dict::checkKeyConstraint
 *
 * @expectedException Exception
 * @dataProvider      providerValidKeyValues
 */
public function testCheckKeyConstraintExistent($key) {
    $this->assertEquals(self::$object, self::$object->checkKeyConstraint($key));
    $this->fail();
}

public function providerNonexistentKeys() {
    $data = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $data[] = array('randKey:' . rand());
        $data[] = array(rand());
    }

    return $data;
}

public function providerValidKeyValues() {
    $data = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $stub   = new Key('id#' . $i, 'val#' . $i . '#string');
        $data[] = array($stub, $stub);
        $stub   = new Key($i, 'val#' . $i . '#numeric');
        $data[] = array($stub, $stub);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to write `throw new Exception('..');` without the `s`

Comment: Actually there was `throw new \Jade\Core\Exceptions\Dict('Key already exists', array('key' => $key));` but I simplified this stuff. Tests are passed well.

Comment: Is it shown as a not-executed line in both cases? could you provide the two test methods, how they are called and what the hasKey method does? perhaps one of those methods throws an exception before the above throw statement is even reached?

Comment: i update the question with sources

Comment: Sorry, but you're showing how you're generating the keys, but not how you're actually passing them to the `testCheckKeyConstraintExistent` member function, if you're not passing anything, it makes sense the error doesn't get thrown (invalid arguments passed) ==> null

Comment: PHPUnit has a way to pass data from data provider to test function see [a brief description](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.dataProvider) The problem was that i was testing an object, which is really does not exists as a key value in Dict, because it is based on PHP array, and arrays can't use objects as a key. Anyway, it's my fault.

Comment: Lol, let that be a lesson: _always_ use type hinting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15294/discussion-between-pinepain-and-elias-van-ootegem)

Comment: BTW, your tests are backwards. `testCheckKeyConstraintExistent` expects an exception while `testCheckKeyConstraintNonExistent` expects the keys to exist.

Comment: I don't get the idea, could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. The problem was that in this `testCheckKeyConstraintExistent` method i check whole object, not it's key. It should be rewritten as:

```
public function testCheckKeyConstraintExistent(Key $key) {
    $this->assertEquals(self::$object, self::$object->checkKeyConstraint($key->_id()));
    $this->fail();
}
```